# Google Play Service Crash in Android Jelly Bean 4.2

Tags: android, google-play-services

I use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0`. It works fine in Lollipop but it **crash** in **Jelly Bean 4.2**. My code like below:

in gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':aFileChoosers')
    //compile project(':cRops')
    compile project(':ucrop')
    compile ('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.0') {
        transitive = false
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The messages that I received like below:

> 03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.R$string 03-04 20:35:39.838
>   27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.(Unknown Source) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.(Unknown
>   Source) 03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown
>   Source) 03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) 03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5097)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4680)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4613)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:162)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 03-04 20:35:39.838
>   27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 03-04 20:35:39.838
>   27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   03-04 20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 03-04
>   20:35:39.838 27252-27252/com.myapp.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How can I fix it? Please anyone for help me.. Big thanks

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services` is extremely huge repository. We use only subrepos: `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` and all works fine. Maybe this can solve your problem.

Comment: I need play-service for google cloud messaging and gps navigation.. so what must i do use?

Comment: I think `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location`. You can view full list here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: but with com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0 it works fine in lolipop.. why it can do?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Maybe some of the play-services module requires minimum SDK as Lollipop. Your meaningful stack trace starts with the following line: `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate`. Maybe without full package `com.google.android.gms.measurement` wouldn't be included into your project.

Comment: Does that help you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fix it.. just change buildToolsVersion from 23.0.1 to 23.0.2.. Maybe gms-play-service 8.4.0 not match with buildToolsVersion 23.0.1